# How does findstr extract the text line I want

Tags: findstr

I have a txt file.Trying to find out alternate of grep in windows to filter specific data.
Below is my input

> 7892:d=4 hl=3 l=5781 cons: cont [ 2 ]

> 52:d=4 hl=3 l=5581 cons: cont [ 0 ]

> 7708:d=4 hl=3 l=4478 cons: cont [ 1 ]

have to get below data

> 52:d=4 hl=3 l=5581 cons: cont [ 0 ]

Below is my command

`findstr ":d=4.*cont [ \0 ]"`

This is not working for me. Please suggest the right pattern searching for me .

Comment: Are these the only three? Whether there are more test rows？

Comment: Yes, about 50 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. My local tests were successful, and **findstr** seemed to differ on the command line from the **regular expression** used on the Web page.

```
findstr ":d=4.*\[.*0"
```

Comment: They all have the same format.